# Working on Complex Field

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Given $D := {z ∈ C : \arg(z) ∈ [0, π]}$ I have to find $E := {z^{\frac14} : z ∈ D}$. I've tried this: $$z=r(\cos\theta+i \sin \theta)$$

Then use DeMoivre formula so I obtain the generic argument of $z^{\frac14}$: $\gamma=\frac{\theta}{4}+\frac{k\pi}{2}$ Here I don't know how to proceed because I don't know how I can arrive to the solutions that are

$$E =z ∈ C : \arg(z) ∈ \Big[0,\frac \pi 4\Big] \cup \Big[\fracπ2,\frac{3π}4\Big] \cup \Big[π, \frac{5π}4\Big] \cup \Big[\frac{3π}2,\frac{7π}4\Big]$$

I also don't know why these are the solutions. So how can I solve this problem.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: hello can u help me understand the way you state the question ? I am not USA and your notation is unclear for me.           Are you searching all the complex number X such as X = z^(1/4) for any z inside D ?

Comment: I have to find $X=z^{\frac14}$ that satisfies the condition of $D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. Notice that $k = 0,1,2,3$.
Plugging that in gets you the result.
For example, let $\phi$ be the argument of $z^{\frac{1}{4}}$ then for $k=1$,  $\phi = \frac{\theta}{4}+\frac{\pi}{2}$ and since $0 \le \theta \le \pi$ then you get $\frac{\pi}{2} \le \phi \le \frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: I really don't get it..

Comment: @Dipok please see my update

Comment: Ok now it's clear ;)